# How to send a query parameter containing == statement in Integration Studio?

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

In Integration Studio, I am working on generating a new API by taking the query parameter from outside and sending it to an API that runs the query parameter as follows. The query structure of the endpoint I call works as follows.

Integration Studio Call http endpoint:
http://localhost:8080/Energy?q=year>2019;month==1

WSO2 Integration Studio Generated API
http://localhost:8290/Energy/Test?q=year>2019;month==1

This is how I will send the query parameter (year>2019;month==1) that I will get from outside. But it does not accept == character.
I can get the part up to the == statement in the Query parameter, but not the == and beyond.
Below is my sample xml work.

Example Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/Energy" name="Energy" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/Test">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="$url:q" name="uri.var.ep.q" scope="default" 
    type="STRING"/>
        <log>
            <property expression="$url:q" name="QueryParameter"/>
        </log>
        <call>
            <endpoint>
                <http method="get" uri-template="http://localhost:8080/Energy?q== 
                {uri.var.ep.q}">
                    <suspendOnFailure>
                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                        <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                        <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                    </suspendOnFailure>
                    <markForSuspension>
                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                    </markForSuspension>
                </http>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var data = mc.getPayloadJSON();
        mc.setPayloadJSON(JSON.stringify(data));]]></script>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" 
        value="application/json"/>
        <jsontransform description="convert to json">
            <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value="true"/>
            <property name="synapse.commons.enableXmlNullForEmptyElement" 
         value="false"/>
        </jsontransform>
        <respond/>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence/>
     <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
   </api>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are reserved when it comes to URI construction. For example according to [RFC2396](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) following characters are reserved and you are not able to use them as values in query parameters, path parameters, or in the URI itself.

> reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
> "$" | ","

If you want to use these special characters you need to use [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to encode the special characters, there are online tools for [encoding](https://www.urlencoder.org/) as well.

In your case, you can use the following URL when calling the API which will allow you to extract the query parameters properly.

```
http://localhost:8080/Energy?q=year%3E2019%3Bmonth%3D%3D1
```

Comment: Thanks for answered. We fixed  by using UrlReplace Mediator